# Generic word for describing a tournament or league

Tags: single-word-requests

Im in the middle of designing my database schema and Im looking for a generic word to use for something that could be either a tournament or a league.

**Examples**

- Tournament - Fifa World Cup 2018
- League - Premier League

I have a generic database model where one column currently is named TournamentId, but it feels wrong using TournamentId on a League.

What would be a more generic word, competition?

Comment: The key thing with database design is keeping data *MECE* (mutually exclusive-completely exhaustive). Is the information hierarchically nested with teams within leagues within tournaments? If so then the first two levels for teams and leagues wld be MECE. Is there more than one tournament? If the only differentiator is the *year* of the tournament then create a separate column for year and retain two cols for teams and leagues -- 3 cols in total. If there is more than one tournament then add a fourth col for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Competition** is used regularly on the BBC website in this sense.

> With no side having gone through from 5-0 down at the end of the first leg in any European competition, Klopp will be annoyed they have given Roma that little bit of hope.
> https://www.bbc.com/sport/football/43871379
>
> Manchester City will be the seventh different English club that Liverpool have faced in European competition.
> Jurgen Klopp has beaten Pep Guardiola on five different occasions in all competitions.
> https://www.bbc.com/sport/football/43430473
>
> They have only missed one season of European football's premier competition [the Champions League] since 1993-94. United could still qualify for the Champions League by winning this season's competition.
> https://www.bbc.com/sport/football/26607980

What the winner wins at the end of the season is called *league title* or *cup* (depending on whether the competition is a league or a tournament/cup), *trophy*, or *silverware*.

Comment: Thank you!
I've done some more researching, what do you think about Contest?
English isn't my native language so I don't know how common that word is/when that word is used.

Comment: As to contest, you could check out [this forum](https://dict.leo.org/forum/viewGeneraldiscussion.php?idThread=278473&idForum=4&lang=en&lp=ende) and [this](https://dict.leo.org/forum/viewGeneraldiscussion.php?idThread=1253806&idForum=4&lang=en&lp=ende). I wouldn't recommend it in your particular use case.